# Why the text of a disabled NSButton (or NSButtonCell) is gray?

Tags: cocoa, macos

When i set a Button (NSButton) to be disabled, its text color changes to gray. 
How can i modify this property? I want the text to stay black.

Comment: Yout title doesnt fit to the question's text. NSCell != NSButton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your Title if not the body of the question: it's practically an industry standard to represent disabled screen elements this way, and probably what users expect.

To do something different might be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

try `setTitleColor:forState:`, and pass `UIControlStateDisabled` for the last argument.